# AJAX Login Form - Clicking submit doesn't work

Tags: php, ajax, forms, authentication, pdo

I'm trying to create my own login form, having a few difficulties though.

I want to have a form where the user can log into the website, using AJAX:

1. If user doesn't enter username, show message
2. If user doesn't enter password, show message
3. Check with database if password is correct, if incorrect, show message

The problem is, I've done a little jQuery and next to no AJAX before. I'm trying to learn but haven't had any luck so far! My PHP/PDO script works fine without any AJAX/jQuery and checks all the requirements fine.

My code so far is below:

**index.html**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#add_err").css('display', 'none', 'important');

 $("#login-submit").click(function(){    
      username=$("#username").val();
      password=$("#password").val();


if (username.length < 1)
    errors = errors + "Please enter your username<br/>";

    if (password.length < 1)
    errors = errors + "Please enter your password<br/>";

var errors = "";          

      $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "process-login.php",
        data: "username="+username+"&password="+password,
       success: function(html) {    
        if(html=='true')    {
         window.location="account.php";
        }

        if (errors != "") {
        $("add_err").html(errors).slideDown("fast");
        }
       }
      });
    return false;
});
});

</script>


<div id="login">
<form method="post" id="form" action="process-login.php">
<div class="err" id="add_err"></div>
<fieldset>
<p><input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username"></p>
<p><input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"></p>
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="<?php echo "$redirect" ?>" />
<p><input type="submit" id="login-submit" name="submit" class="button" value="Let me in!"/></p>
<p>Not a member? <a href="/register.php">Sign up now</a> <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></p>
</fieldset>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
session_start();

try
    {
    $dbuser = "XXXXXXXXXXX";
    $dbpass = "XXXXXXXXXXX";
    $dbh    = new PDO('mysql:host=XXXXXXXXXXX', $dbuser, $dbpass);

//Min length validation
function validateMinLength($length, $number){
        //if it's NOT valid
        if(strlen($length) < $number)
            return false;
        //if it's valid
        else
            return true;
    }   
//Max length validation
    function validateMaxLength($length, $number){
        //if it's NOT valid
        if(strlen($length) > $number)
            return false;
        //if it's valid
        else
            return true;
    }       

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $password = strtoupper(hash('whirlpool', $password));
        $redirect = $_POST["redirect"];
        $err = array();

if(!validateMinLength($_POST['username'], 2))$err[]='The username field is too short or empty';     
if(!validateMaxLength($_POST['username'], 21))$err[]='The username field must be less than 21 characters';  

if(!validateMinLength($_POST['password'], 2))$err[]='The password field is too short or empty';

    if(count($err)){
    foreach($err as $one_er){
    echo $one_er . "<br/>"; 
    }
    exit();
    }   

        if (empty($error) === true) {
        $query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1");
        $query->execute(array($username));
            if ($query->rowCount() > 0) {
                $data = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                if ($data->password != $password)
                    {
                    $err[] = "Invalid password";
                    }
                if(count($err)){
                foreach($err as $one_er){
                    echo $one_er . "<br/>"; 
                }
                exit();
                }                       

                else {
                    $query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? AND isadmin = '1'");
                    $query->bindParam(1, $username, PDO::PARAM_STR, 25);
                    $query->execute();
                    if ($query->rowCount() == 1) {
                        $_SESSION["admin"]      = $username;
                        $admin                  = $_SESSION["admin"];
                        $_SESSION['start_time'] = time();
                        $online                 = $dbh->query("UPDATE user SET online=1 WHERE username='$admin'");
                        header('location:http://www.colorshare.co' . $redirect);
                        echo "Success";
                    } else {
                        $_SESSION["member"]     = $username;
                        $member                 = $_SESSION["member"];
                        $_SESSION['start_time'] = time();
                        $online                 = $dbh->query("UPDATE user SET online=1 WHERE username='$member'");
                        header('location:http://www.colorshare.co' . $redirect);
                        echo "Success";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $dbh = null;
    }
catch (PDOException $e)
    {
    print "Error: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
    }
?>
```

Is there something I'm missing or doing completely wrong?

Answer (score 0):

first thing you should check if the php script returning the right values that you testing on the JS side .

then you should check this :

```
    if(html=='true')    {
     window.location="account.php";
    }

    if (errors != "") {
    $("add_err").html(errors).slideDown("fast");
    }
```

you should make it , i think :

```
    if(html=='true')    {
     window.location="account.php";
    }else{
        errors = html ;//when 'html' variable is not returning 'true' the its returning errors
    }

    if (errors != "") {
    $("add_err").html(errors).slideDown("fast");
    }
```

i hope give us more information about the problem like what it's showing when you tested it .

Comment: Hmm, no errors presented. I'm guessing it's something with my process file. - Am I right in thinking I need to RETURN true/false.

Comment: yes you should return true if the credentials was right otherwise return the errors to show it .or false if you error is limited in the js file

Comment: in that case , the problem in the php side .

Comment: the php code gave me "Success" . after i commented the header line . this can be the problem , comment it .and change the javascript errors=""  always .

Comment: replace this if(html=='true')   to if(html.trim()=='Success')

Comment: Just replaced the trim/success, the submit button no longer works :|